# Do we have Manage.py Task in VS code

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code, pycharm, vscode-tasks

I used to work with ***Pycharm*** But now i use ***VS Code*** for coding **Django**, so Does anyone know Do we have **Manage.py Task** in VS code or Do I have a way to make this Task? i use it Many times like when i call `runserver` or `migrate` i Take Screenshot from it in pycharm it is located below ->
[pycharm Manage.py Task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7uu9.png)

I just need a button that opens Terminal (CMD) + `'Python Manage.py ...'` when I click on it And do not need to Write `'Python Manage.py'` several time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At present, there is no such button to execute the "Django" project in VSCode. We need to use the command "`python manage.py runserver`" to execute it.

After VSCode uses this command to execute the Django project, when we change the content of the project, the VSCode terminal will automatically update, just refresh the web page of the browser, and the updated content is already used.

In addition, they are two different tools after all, it is difficult to require them to be exactly the same in use, but if you encounter any technical problems when using VSCode, please let us know.

Reference: [Django in VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/tutorial-django).

Answer (score 0):

**This could be apply to other Commands, like create app, superuser, etc.**

In VSCode task are executed with Open the Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+P in Linux). There, you type/find `>Tasks: Run Task` and press enter. Then Select configure one task. It will show you a simple echo example:

```
{
// See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
// for the documentation about the tasks.json format
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "label": "echo",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "echo Hello"
    }
}
```

In this case you edit it so, you can execute `python manage.py runserver`, at first instace you could try add it like this:

```
{
// See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
// for the documentation about the tasks.json format
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "label": "Runserver",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "python manage.py runserver"
    },
}
```

But I got error of syntax, which was weird because executing directly on the shell was ok. So, as I use `environments` I explicitly specify the python of that environment.

**The result is**

```
{
// See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
// for the documentation about the tasks.json format
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "label": "Runserver",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "./my_env_testing_blog/bin/python3 ./manage.py runserver",
    },
]
}
```

Where `"./my_env_testing_blog/` is the path to my project environment.

So, now when I open the Command Palette, and select the `Task: Run Task` options appears the task: `Runserver`

**This could be apply to other Commands, like create app, superuser, etc.**